# Nginx -Gitlab: could not clone over https

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I starting setting up a gitlab-runner, before I only try to clone, pull, push, etc. over ssh. With ssh it was no problem, so I think it is a problem with nginx. I try some settings in nginx, but not clearly sure what will be need. Do anybody know what to set, to get data? Website is also running fine.

The **nginx output** while cloning git repo ci https:

```
        172.17.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2017:21:13:39 +0000] "GET /server/nginx.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 26 "-" "git/2.7.4"
    172.17.0.1 - user [20/Jul/2017:21:13:39 +0000] "GET /server/nginx.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 26 "-" "git/2.7.4"
172.17.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2017:21:13:42 +0000] "POST /heartbeat HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
    172.17.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2017:21:13:46 +0000] "GET /ocs/v2.php/apps/notifications/api/v2/notifications HTTP/1.1" 200 74 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
    172.17.0.1 - user [20/Jul/2017:21:13:47 +0000] "GET /server/nginx.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 415 "-" "git/2.7.4"
    172.17.0.1 - user [20/Jul/2017:21:13:47 +0000] "POST /server/nginx.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "-" "git/2.7.4"
```

**git response:**

```
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

**git workhorse error message**

```
    2017-07-22_11:19:45.43536 2017/07/22 11:19:45 error: POST "/server/nginx.git/git-upload-pack": handleUploadPack: ReadAllTempfile: open /tmp/gitlab-workhorse-read-all-tempfile358528589: permission denied
2017-07-22_11:19:45.43551 git.dropanote.de 172.10.11.97:43758 - - [2017-07-22 11:19:45.349933226 +0000 UTC] "POST /server/nginx.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "" "git/2.7.4" 0.085399
```

**nginx config**

```
    ## GitLab
##
## Modified from nginx http version
## Modified from http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/04/21/tutorial-setting-up-gitlab-on-debian-6/
## Modified from https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html
##
## Lines starting with two hashes (##) are comments with information.
## Lines starting with one hash (#) are configuration parameters that can be uncommented.
##
##################################
##        CONTRIBUTING          ##
##################################
##
## If you change this file in a Merge Request, please also create
## a Merge Request on https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/merge_requests
##
###################################
##         configuration         ##
###################################
##
## See installation.md#using-https for additional HTTPS configuration details.

upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  server 172.10.11.66:8181;
  keepalive 32;
}

## Redirects all HTTP traffic to the HTTPS host
server {
  ## Either remove "default_server" from the listen line below,
  ## or delete the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file. This will cause gitlab
  ## to be served if you visit any address that your server responds to, eg.
  ## the ip address of the server (http://x.x.x.x/)
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
  server_name url.tdl; ## Replace this with something like gitlab.example.com
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /tmp;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;
    }
}

## HTTPS host
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on ssl;
  server_name url.tdl; ## Replace this with something like gitlab.example.com
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice
  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;



  ## Strong SSL Security
  ## https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html & https://cipherli.st/
  ssl on;
    ssl_certificate linkto/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key linkto/privkey.pem;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains" always;

  # GitLab needs backwards compatible ciphers to retain compatibility with Java IDEs
  ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 5m;



  location / {
    client_max_body_size 0;
    gzip off;

    ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_read_timeout      3000;
    proxy_connect_timeout   3000;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it solved the problem by remove the tmp folder from mapped docker folder. Before I mapped the tmp folder to my host systems. I do not know why, but gitlab got a problem to write to this folder and that seems to be the problem of http connection.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running `gitlab-workhorse`, check your `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` with this lines uncommented:

```
gitlab_workhorse['enable'] = true
gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"
```

then run

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
...
ok: run: gitlab-workhorse: ...
```

Seems like everything is ok with your `nginx.conf` for me.

Comment: Yes I set this, only change the ip to the docker container ip because otherwise it is not reachable from nginx container

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), "[`git upload-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9fc3a987b9611fa6b71e38768657b10f84fef7f/Documentation/git-upload-pack.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack))</sup> (the other side of "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d9fc3a987b9611fa6b71e38768657b10f84fef7f/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup>) should be more robust.

It used a 8kB buffer but most of its payload came on 64kB "packets".
The buffer size has been enlarged so that such a packet fits.

This is a contribution directly from GitLab staff ([Jacob Vosmaer](https://gitlab.com/jacobvosmaer-gitlab)).

See [commit 55a9651](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55a9651d26a6b88c68445e7d6c9f511d1207cbd8) (14 Dec 2021) by [Jacob Vosmaer (`jacobvosmaer`)](https://github.com/jacobvosmaer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d9fc3a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9fc3a987b9611fa6b71e38768657b10f84fef7f), 05 Jan 2022)</sup>

> ### [`upload-pack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55a9651d26a6b88c68445e7d6c9f511d1207cbd8): increase output buffer size
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jacob Vosmaer</sup>

> When serving a fetch, [`git upload-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/55a9651d26a6b88c68445e7d6c9f511d1207cbd8/Documentation/git-upload-pack.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack))</sup> copies data from a [`git pack-objects`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/55a9651d26a6b88c68445e7d6c9f511d1207cbd8/Documentation/git-pack-objects.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-objects))</sup> stdout pipe to its stdout.
> This commit increases the size of the buffer used for that copying from 8192 to 65515, the maximum sideband-64k packet size.
>
> Previously, this buffer was allocated on the stack.
> Because the new buffer size is nearly 64KB, we switch this to a heap allocation.
>
> On GitLab.com we use GitLab's pack-objects cache which does writes of 65515 bytes.
> Because of the default 8KB buffer size, propagating these cache writes requires 8 pipe reads and 8 pipe writes from `git-upload-pack`, and 8 pipe reads from Gitaly (our Git RPC service).
> If we increase the size of the buffer to the maximum Git packet size, we need only 1 pipe read and 1 pipe write in `git-upload-pack`, and 1 pipe read in Gitaly to transfer the same amount of data.
> In benchmarks with a pure fetch and 100% cache hit rate workload we are seeing CPU utilization reductions of over 30%.